# JS Event Listener check on PHP session infinitely

Tags: javascript, php

I want my page to consistently check if the user session is still active.
if using event listener. My concern is that php file execution time is limited. is there way to set php execution to infinite? or is there a better way of doing this?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loginSource = new EventSource("/structure/ajax/check_login_session.php");

    loginSource.addEventListener("login-verification", function(e) {
        var response = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (data.login_failed) {
            login_fail_redirect();
        }
    });
})
```

php

```
function send_response() {

    if (empty($_SESSION['user_info']) || empty($_SESSION['user_info']['active'])) {

        $response = array("status" => "failed", "login_failed" => 1);

    } else {

        $response = array("status" => "success", "login_failed" => 0);

    }

    echo "event: login-verification\n";
    echo 'data: '.json_encode($response);
    echo "\n\n";
    flush();

}
while (true) {
    send_response();
    sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: I don't think consistently checking if a user session is open is a good idea. It's probably better to get a notification that a user left using `onbeforeunload()` or `onunload()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a javascript `setInterval` instead. It will send timed requests to the backend to check if the session is active or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function {
        var loginSource = new EventSource("/structure/ajax/check_login_session.php");

        loginSource.addEventListener("login-verification", function(e) {
            var response = JSON.parse(e.data);
            if (data.login_failed) {
                login_fail_redirect();
            }
        });
    },1000); //time in ms
})
```

Then **replace** this code from your backend:

```
while (true) {
    send_response();
    sleep(2);
}
```

to

```
send_response();
```